# XSLT: combine multiple unrelated elements into one element

Tags: xml, xslt, dublin-core

I am transforming qualified Dublin Core into MODS. I need to combine two elements into one, and other posts I've found here aren't applicable because they match on a parent element.

Dublin Core is problematic with XSLT because it does not have parent and child elements... so I am not sure which to select.

Here's some sample input (the important bits are the dc:coverage elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
  <oai_dc:dc (schema etc.)>
        <dc:title>This is the title</dc:title>
        <dc:creator>Author McAuthorson</dc:creator>
        <dc:type>Article</dc:type>
        <dc:coverage.spatial.lat>49.101</dc:coverage.spatial.lat>
        <dc:coverage.spatial.long>-122.720</dc:coverage.spatial.long>
  </oai_dc:dc>
```

And here's the output I need for the dc:coverage elements:

```
<subject>
  <cartographics>
    <coordinates>49.101, -122.720</coordinates>
  </cartographics>
</subject>
```

I've read solutions that can process different elements with the same name, but nothing that can combine two elements with different names. I've experimented with setting these up as variables, but can't work out how to pass the variable from one template (e.g. matching dc:coverage.spatial.lat) into the next (matching dc:coverage.spatial.long). So I'm kind of flying blind.

Any advice (or links to applicable answers that I couldn't find) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can there be multiple lat/long pairs under the same parent (`oai_dc:dc` in your example)?

Comment: No - there's only one set of lat/long pairs per record.

Comment: I would question your strategy for teaching yourself XSLT. You can't learn a programming language by searching the web for examples that do exactly what you want. You need to learn the principles and master the building blocks so that you can combine them to create your own solutions to your particular problems. If you can't work out how to pass variables from one template to another, then you're not getting your information from the right place. Get yourself a good XSLT book, and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/oai_dc:dc">
    <subject>
        <cartographics>
            <coordinates>
                <xsl:value-of select="dc:coverage.spatial.lat" />
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="dc:coverage.spatial.long" />
            </coordinates>
        </cartographics>
    </subject>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: michael.hor257k: Gave that a try... Doesn't work because this is just a small piece of a much larger XSLT (with many more elements than in my example). This solution produces output that ignores all of the other elements/transforms.

Comment: @Brandon You need to add code for processing the other nodes that you want to include in your output. Unfortunately, I have no way of knowing what those might be and how they need to be handled. Please review: [mcve].